# Image path returns 404 error (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to access an image I have saved in a nested directory. I am using React and JSX, so the path to the file I want the image to be saved in looks like this: root/client/components/home/service.jsx. The path to the image looks like this: root/server/public/images/Mercedes-Benz-logo.png. In the img tag src attribute, I have tried the following paths:

```
/server/public/images/Mercedes-Benz-logo.png
../../../server/public/images/Mercedes-Benz-logo.png
./../../../server/public/images/Mercedes-Benz-logo.png
```

All of these respond with an error of 404 (Not Found). Any help or explanation as to why this is happening would be appreciated. If you would like to look at my source code, [click here](https://github.com/NicBonetto/rubens-imports/issues/1) to see my Github repo. I haven't merged any pull requests yet, so you will have to click on individual commits. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you don't simply have a case issue - the actual files use a small "m", but your listed files have a capital "M".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'))`, any file will need to be referenced from that folder. Here you can just pretend that your public folder is where the files will be served.  To get to an image, just use the path relative to the `public` folder → `/images/Mercedes-Benz-logo.png`

Comment: Thank you! Solved the issue.